# The Earth as seen from the Moon; why "as"?

Tags: grammar, as

> 1. The Earth as seen from the Moon.
> 2. The Earth seen from the Moon.

I know the first one is actually "as it's seen from", but exactly when do you put 'as' and when not? How are the two sentences different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"seen from the Moon" means that the image is taken while being on the Moon.

"as seen from the Moon" can refer to an image created by a simulation, to give the impression that it was taken while being on the Moon.

Google maps can be thought of seeing the Earth "as seen from the Moon".

The pictures taken by Neil Armstrong and his colleagues are images of the Earth "seen from the Moon".

---

Of course, "as seen from the Moon" is generic and it includes "seen from the Moon".

Comment: Hi. I'm just here to ask a few more. Could you explain this as well please, like you did? "The deployment of new laboratory-created plant hybrids, made using carefully selected segments of the Baol genetic code as harvested from the body of the last Baol, successfully transformed Earth's climate." Why 'as' here?